# Flushing a Gembox Spreadsheet object to a stream while reading from a DataReader

Tags: asp.net, memory-management, gembox-spreadsheet

Here's the scenario:

- I have around 400k records in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that I want to export to an XLSX spreadsheet.
- The application is an ASP.NET 4.0 web application

I tried using a DataTable with ReportViewer but the w3wp process memory usage skyrockets due to the entire DataTable being read into memory.

I thought that Gembox Spreadsheet would handle that scenario a little better, guessing that I could use a DataReader instead of the DataTable and just write a new row to the Excel workbook sheet and flush it over the HTTP stream.
But I can't find that function anywhere in Gembox Spreadsheet. Has anyone achieved anything similar, either with Gembox or any other 3rd party component?

Comment: Would it make sense to spit out 400k records in smaller chunks, lets say 10k. That way you wont run into memory problem.

Comment: It makes sense but that's not doable with ReportViewer as I'd have to push everything into a DataTable in the end, which would defeat the implementation you suggested. The same applies to Gembox.

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing it here but you should be able to do it using SQLDataReader. SQL DataReader is different than SQL DataSet. The former retrieves one record at a time and it required live connection to DB. It should not create memory problem, I think. The later retrieves the whole table at once which can sky rocket the memory usage. Here is a good article from Microsoft, [difference between datareader and dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188717.aspx)

Also note that Excel has limitation as well. Excel 2007 is pretty good by the way, can handle 1000k x 16k records. Older versions of Excel are definitely more limited. [Excel 2007 Limitation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx)

I am also thinking if Excel can handle such a large file , your program should handle 400k records. I know that is a lot of data but Operating System usually takes care of memory management unless you are doing something that is just plain wrong.

Comment: That would work if the ReportViewer accepted a DataReader as input, but it looks like it only works with DataSet and DataTable AFAIK.